# Как в Android Studio в одном проекте реализовать сборку разных APK под разные магазины приложений?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

Нужно собирать приложение под разные магазины (AppGallery, Google Play например). Они используют разные библиотеки. Знаю, что через Gradle это как-то можно сделать.

А также, как в самом Java коде реализовать разные инициализации платежных библиотек, так чтобы при сборке под Google использовался один код, а под AppGallery другой и т.д.?

Comment: Да в gradle можете создать различные сборки с помощью productFlavors, а после исходя из сборки делать проверку в java файлах

Comment: Вот тут я писал как раз про то что вы спрашиваете: разные варианты сборок на примере использования аналитики, геолокации и карт https://medium.com/@mohax.spb